# .NET 4, C++, how if...else and switch() affect on performance

Tags: c++, .net, performance, algorithm

Now in my app I am using this structure

```
if (e->UserState->Equals(1)) {} //stuff 1
else if (e->UserState->Equals(2)) {} //stuff 2
... // e - EventArgs of .NET 4 WebClient class
```

Should I better define

```
int n = (int)e->UserState;
```

And use switch()

```
switch(n)
{
  case 1:
  //stuff 1
  break;

  case 2:
  //stuff 2
  break;
}
```

Will it affect somehow on performance? (about 15 variants of e->UserState)

Answer (score 3):

> (about 15 variants of e->UserState)

I would write it in `switch` form purely for readability purposes! As for performance, you can check with profiling, but I doubt the difference if any would be statistically significant.

Answer (score 1):

Switch case will be faster (in this case) since compiler can do lots of tricks to make it faster, like table of jumps where value is used as a index to that table or binary search.
Note that if conditions in 'if's contains only variables and constants, compiler may do same tricks, but if you are calling some functions/methods inside conditions compiler have to do each check sequentially to keep side effects which may accrue inside this functions.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is not the key factor here (since it's negligibly) but readability. So etiher use `switch` or even a method:

```
public static void Stuff(UserState state)
{
    // do your stuff here ...
}
```

now you can use this (assuming `UserState` is an existing enum):

```
UserState state = (UserState)(int)e;
Stuff(state);
```